# ExtJS 4 textfield regex

Tags: regex, forms, extjs, textfield

I don't know but I think there's propably error in textfield regex.
I have field for hour and minute information entered if format HHMM,
so fisrt number have to be 0, 1 or 2 .... and so on. I use regex:

```
/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][05]$/
```

It is working almost good but I can enter value "2395"
and I can't see error. Value is accepted. Anybody could say me why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `timefield` component you can just set `format: 'Hi'` config and it will handle the time input for you.

Comment: Thanks, no it's only textfield.